# Filter Pyspark dataframe column with None value

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to filter a PySpark dataframe that has `None` as a row value:

```
df.select('dt_mvmt').distinct().collect()

[Row(dt_mvmt=u'2016-03-27'),
 Row(dt_mvmt=u'2016-03-28'),
 Row(dt_mvmt=u'2016-03-29'),
 Row(dt_mvmt=None),
 Row(dt_mvmt=u'2016-03-30'),
 Row(dt_mvmt=u'2016-03-31')]
```

and I can filter correctly with an string value:

```
df[df.dt_mvmt == '2016-03-31']
# some results here
```

but this fails:

```
df[df.dt_mvmt == None].count()
0
df[df.dt_mvmt != None].count()
0
```

But there are definitely values on each category. What's going on?

Comment: You actually want to filter rows with null values, not a column with None values. The title could be misleading.

Comment: In a nutshell, a comparison involving null (or None, in this case) always returns false. In particular, the comparison (null == null) returns false. Also, the comparison (None == None) returns false.

Answer (score 317, accepted):

You can use `Column.isNull` / `Column.isNotNull`:

```
df.where(col("dt_mvmt").isNull())

df.where(col("dt_mvmt").isNotNull())
```

If you want to simply drop `NULL` values you can use `na.drop` with `subset` argument:

```
df.na.drop(subset=["dt_mvmt"])
```

Equality based comparisons with `NULL` won't work because in SQL `NULL` is undefined so any attempt to compare it with another value returns `NULL`:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT NULL = NULL").show()
## +-------------+
## |(NULL = NULL)|
## +-------------+
## |         null|
## +-------------+


sqlContext.sql("SELECT NULL != NULL").show()
## +-------------------+
## |(NOT (NULL = NULL))|
## +-------------------+
## |               null|
## +-------------------+
```

The only valid method to compare value with `NULL` is `IS` / `IS NOT` which are equivalent to the `isNull` / `isNotNull` method calls.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I thought that these filters on PySpark dataframes would be more "pythonic", but alas, they're not. I'm thinking on asking the devs about this.

Comment: Actually it is quite Pythonic. You should never check `__eq__` with None ;) And `is` wouldn't work because it doesn't behave the same way.

Comment: Strangely this only works for string columns... It seems like `df.filter("dt_mvmt is not NULL")` handles both.

Answer (score 48):

Try to just use [isNotNull](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html) function.

```
df.filter(df.dt_mvmt.isNotNull()).count()
```

Answer (score 22):

To obtain entries whose values in the `dt_mvmt` column are not null we have

```
df.filter("dt_mvmt is not NULL")
```

and for entries which are null we have

```
df.filter("dt_mvmt is NULL")
```

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple ways you can remove/filter the null values from a column in DataFrame.

Lets create a simple DataFrame with below code:

```
date = ['2016-03-27','2016-03-28','2016-03-29', None, '2016-03-30','2016-03-31']
df = spark.createDataFrame(date, StringType())
```

Now you can try one of the below approach to filter out the null values.

```
# Approach - 1
df.filter("value is not null").show()

# Approach - 2
df.filter(col("value").isNotNull()).show()

# Approach - 3
df.filter(df["value"].isNotNull()).show()

# Approach - 4
df.filter(df.value.isNotNull()).show()

# Approach - 5
df.na.drop(subset=["value"]).show()

# Approach - 6
df.dropna(subset=["value"]).show()

# Note: You can also use where function instead of a filter.
```

You can also check the section "Working with NULL Values" on my [blog](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/start-your-journey-with-apache-spark-part-3-1ae77c05187) for more information.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

`isNull()`/`isNotNull()` will return the respective rows which have `dt_mvmt` as Null or !Null.

```
method_1 = df.filter(df['dt_mvmt'].isNotNull()).count()
method_2 = df.filter(df.dt_mvmt.isNotNull()).count()
```

Both will return the same result

Answer (score 3):

if column = None

```
COLUMN_OLD_VALUE
----------------
None
1
None
100
20
------------------
```

Use 
create a temptable on data frame:

```
sqlContext.sql("select * from tempTable where column_old_value='None' ").show()
```

So use : `column_old_value='None'`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep with the Pandas syntex this worked for me.

```
df = df[df.dt_mvmt.isNotNull()]
```

Answer (score 2):

None/Null is a data type of the class NoneType in PySpark/Python
so, below will not work as you are trying to compare NoneType object with the string object

###### Wrong way of filreting

```
df[df.dt_mvmt == None].count()
```

0

```
df[df.dt_mvmt != None].count()
```

0

### correct

```
df=df.where(col("dt_mvmt").isNotNull())
```

returns all records with `dt_mvmt` as None/Null

Answer (score 1):

PySpark provides various filtering options based on arithmetic, logical and other conditions. Presence of NULL values can hamper further processes. Removing them or statistically imputing them could be a choice.

Below set of code can be considered:

```
# Dataset is df
# Column name is dt_mvmt
# Before filtering make sure you have the right count of the dataset
df.count() # Some number

# Filter here
df = df.filter(df.dt_mvmt.isNotNull())

# Check the count to ensure there are NULL values present (This is important when dealing with large dataset)
df.count() # Count should be reduced if NULL values are present
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter out records having None value in column then see below example:

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([[123,"abc"],[234,"fre"],[345,None]],["a","b"])
```

Now filter out null value records:

```
df=df.filter(df.b.isNotNull())

df.show()
```

If you want to remove those records from DF then see below:

```
df1=df.na.drop(subset=['b'])

df1.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

in pyspark ，you can use：

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.filter(col("dt_mvmt").isNull()).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

df = df.filter(df['dt_mvmt'].isNull()).count()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).