# Spark assign value if null to column (python)

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

Assuming that I have the following data

```
+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
|              values|count|             values2|
+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
|              aaaaaa|  249|                null|
|              bbbbbb|  166|                  b2|
|              cccccc| 1680|           something|
+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
```

So if there is a null value in `values2` column how to assign the `values1` column to it? So the result should be:

```
+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
|              values|count|             values2|
+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
|              aaaaaa|  249|              aaaaaa|
|              bbbbbb|  166|                  b2|
|              cccccc| 1680|           something|
+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
```

I thought of something of the following but it doesnt work:

```
df.na.fill({"values2":df['values']}).show()
```

I found this way to solve it but there should be something more clear forward:

```
def change_null_values(a,b):
    if b:
        return b
    else:
        return a

udf_change_null = udf(change_null_values,StringType())

df.withColumn("values2",udf_change_null("values","values2")).show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter Pyspark dataframe column with None value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262762/filter-pyspark-dataframe-column-with-none-value)

Comment: @Mpizos Dimitris, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61964179/pyspark-mapping-multiple-variables?noredirect=1#comment109595813_61964179

Answer (score 5):

You can use https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce

```
df.withColumn('values2', coalesce(df.values2, df.values)).show()
```

Comment: Can we ingest our own value like 0 or something ?

Answer (score 4):

Following up on @shadow_dev's method :

```
    df.withColumn("values2", 
                  when(col("values2").isNull(), col("values1"))
                  .otherwise(col("values2")))
```

Dmytro Popovych's solution is still the cleanest.

If one needs more fancy when/otherwise logic :

```
df.withColumn("values2", when(col("values2").isNull() | col("values3").isNull(), col("values1"))
.when(col("values1") == col("values2"), 1)
.otherwise(0))
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the column attribute `.isNull()`.

```
df.where(col("dt_mvmt").isNull())

df.where(col("dt_mvmt").isNotNull())
```

This answer comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262762/filter-pyspark-dataframe-column-with-none-value) answer - I just don't have enough reputation to add a comment.

Comment: Doesn't provide complete solution to the issue. Only hints towards the solution.