# Pyspark Removing null values from a column in dataframe

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark

My Dataframe looks like below

```
ID,FirstName,LastName

1,Navee,Srikanth

2,,Srikanth 

3,Naveen,
```

Now My Problem statement is I have to remove the row number 2 since First Name is null.

I am using below pyspark script

```
join_Df1= Name.filter(Name.col(FirstName).isnotnull()).show()
```

I am getting error as

```
  File "D:\0\NameValidation.py", line 13, in <module>
join_Df1= filter(Name.FirstName.isnotnull()).show()
```

> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Can anyone please help me on this to resolve

Comment: Check out the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262762/filter-pyspark-dataframe-column-with-none-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter Pyspark dataframe column with None value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262762/filter-pyspark-dataframe-column-with-none-value)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like your DataFrame FirstName have empty value instead `Null`. Below are some options to try out:-

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[1,'Navee','Srikanth'], [2,'','Srikanth'] , [3,'Naveen','']], ['ID','FirstName','LastName'])
df.show()
+---+---------+--------+
| ID|FirstName|LastName|
+---+---------+--------+
|  1|    Navee|Srikanth|
|  2|         |Srikanth|
|  3|   Naveen|        |
+---+---------+--------+

df.where(df.FirstName.isNotNull()).show() #This doen't remove null because df have empty value
+---+---------+--------+
| ID|FirstName|LastName|
+---+---------+--------+
|  1|    Navee|Srikanth|
|  2|         |Srikanth|
|  3|   Naveen|        |
+---+---------+--------+

df.where(df.FirstName != '').show()
+---+---------+--------+
| ID|FirstName|LastName|
+---+---------+--------+
|  1|    Navee|Srikanth|
|  3|   Naveen|        |
+---+---------+--------+

df.filter(df.FirstName != '').show()
+---+---------+--------+
| ID|FirstName|LastName|
+---+---------+--------+
|  1|    Navee|Srikanth|
|  3|   Naveen|        |
+---+---------+--------+

df.where("FirstName != ''").show()
+---+---------+--------+
| ID|FirstName|LastName|
+---+---------+--------+
|  1|    Navee|Srikanth|
|  3|   Naveen|        |
+---+---------+--------+
```

Answer (score 7):

You should be doing as below

```
join_Df1.filter(join_Df1.FirstName.isNotNull()).show
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

I think what you might need is this `notnull()`.

So this is your input in csv file `my_test.csv`:

```
ID,FirstName,LastName
1,Navee,Srikanth

2,,Srikanth

3,Naveen
```

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("my_test.csv")

print(df[df['FirstName'].notnull()])
```

output:

```
  ID FirstName  LastName
0   1     Navee  Srikanth
2   3    Naveen       NaN
```

This is what you would like! `df[df['FirstName'].notnull()]`

output of `df['FirstName'].notnull()`:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
```

This creates a dataframe `df` where `df['FirstName'].notnull()` returns `True`

How this is checked?  `df['FirstName'].notnull()` If the value for `FirstName` column is notnull return `True` else if `NaN` is present return `False`.

Comment: The question is about PySpark not Pandas