# How to return rows with Null values in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get the rows with null values from a pyspark dataframe. In pandas, I can achieve this using `isnull()` on the dataframe:

```
df = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

But in case of PySpark, when I am running below command it shows Attributeerror:

```
df.filter(df.isNull())
```

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'isNull'.

How can get the rows with null values without checking it for each column?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262762/filter-pyspark-dataframe-column-with-none-value

Comment: @Mikhail I think that the question linked is not the answer because this question ask about all columns at the same time, without checking for each column.

Answer (score 10):

You can filter the rows with `where`, `reduce` and a list comprehension. For example, given the following dataframe:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    (0.4, 0.3),
    (None, 0.11),
    (9.7, None), 
    (None, None)
]).toDF(["A", "B"])

df.show()
+----+----+
|   A|   B|
+----+----+
| 0.4| 0.3|
|null|0.11|
| 9.7|null|
|null|null|
+----+----+
```

Filtering the rows with some `null` value could be achieved with:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from functools import reduce

df.where(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, (f.col(x).isNull() for x in df.columns))).show()
```

Which gives:

```
+----+----+
|   A|   B|
+----+----+
|null|0.11|
| 9.7|null|
|null|null|
+----+----+
```

In the condition statement you have to specify if any (or, |), all (and, &), etc.

Comment: Good answer, I was wondering how I could construct the boolean expression programmatically

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do this in scala

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class Test(id:Int, weight:Option[Int], age:Int, gender: Option[String])

val df1 = Seq(Test(1, Some(100), 23, Some("Male")), Test(2, None, 25, None), Test(3, None, 33, Some("Female"))).toDF()
    
display(df1.filter(df1.columns.map(c => col(c).isNull).reduce((a,b) => a || b)))
```