# None/== vs Null/isNull in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What is the difference between:

```
F.when(F.col('Name').isNull())
```

and:

```
F.when(F.col('Name') == None)
```

They don't appear to work the same. The first one seems to work better when checking for null values in a column. Sometimes the second method doesn't work for checking null Names. For example if I wanted to check null values and replace the Names that are null to "Missing name" or something, the second method won't do anything sometimes. I'm not sure why it works some times and not other times. But the first method always works.

Comment: Well, that’s a suspect “reason” to close the question..

Comment: `is None` instead of `== None` is the correct way to check for Nones

Comment: Related to bits of the question and some answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3257919/2864740

Answer (score 2):

```
F.when(F.col('Name') == None)
```

None is an object in python, `NoneType`. It's not the same as an empty string or 0. For this instance, you would want to use

```
F.when(F.col('Name') is None)
```

Using `==` you're checking to see if `F.col('Name')` value equals the None object which is going to throw things off.

Comment: The OP asks about “isNull” vs “== None”. While “is None” *is* preferred, such is secondary and should have no relevant impact .. maybe a miscopy of the original question?

Comment: I tried to explain OP's original question with an example.  Pls take a look.  Hope this explanation will help people to undertand difference b/w isNull and == None

Answer (score 2):

Refer here : [Filter Pyspark dataframe column with None value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262762/filter-pyspark-dataframe-column-with-none-value)

> Equality based comparisons with NULL won't work because in SQL NULL is undefined so any attempt to compare it with another value returns NULL

Comment: Coming from a LINQ background, feels like a historical (annoyance) restriction in the mapping to SQL .. oh well. For reference, LINQ normally converts “== null” (code) to “is NULL”, separating the rules of each layer. Is this specific to Spark, or how does the Python Database API define the operation? That is, can the answer (in Python) be generalized more consistently?

Answer (score 1):

In data world, two `Null` values (or for the matter two `None`) are not identical.

Therefore, if you perform `==` or `!=` operation with two `None` values, it always results in `False`. That is the key reason `isNull()` or `isNotNull()` functions are built for.

Please take a look at below example for better understanding -

Creating a `dataframe` with few valid records and one record with `None`

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

lst = [(1,'sometext'),(2,''),(3, None),(4, 'someothertext')]

myrdd = sc.parallelize(lst).map(lambda x: Row(id=x[0], txt=x[1]))
mydf= sqlContext.createDataFrame(myrdd)
```

`isNull()` returns `True` for Row#3, thus below statement returns one row -

```
mydf.filter(col("txt").isNull()).show(truncate=False)
+---+----+
|id |txt |
+---+----+
|3  |null|
+---+----+
```

`==` operator returns `False` for Row#3, thus no records are filtered out.

```
mydf.filter(col("txt") == None).show(truncate=False)
+---+---+
|id |txt|
+---+---+
+---+---+
```