# Pyspark/R: is there a pyspark equivalent function for R's is.na?

Tags: r, pyspark

In R, the is.na() function returns a dataset where Null values are true, while Not Null values are false:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Null | 1 |
| 1 | Null |
| Null | Null |
| 1 | 1 |

is.na() -->

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| True | False |
| False | True |
| True | True |
| False | False |

I'm wondering if there is an equivalent pyspark function that returns the dataframe, populated with True/False values, I do not want to use pyspark filter/where as that will not return the full dataset.

Thanks in advance!

PS: If my formatting is off, please let me know, this is my first stack overflow post so not 100% sure how the formatting works

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37262762/3358272 and https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-filter-rows-with-null-values/

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, that's not quite what I was looking for - as those both filter records out of the dataset, instead I found solution:
`df.withColumn('col1', when(df['col1'].isNull(), lit('True')).otherwise(lit('False')))` and repeating for col2 --> This returns the whole dataset with any null values replaced with True, and any non-null values replaced with False