# Spark return corresponding NULL value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data in a dataframe:

| ID | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NY |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | LA |
| 4 | NULL |

I would like to return the corresponding ID associated to the NULL value from the table above. As a result, the final outcome should be "**ID = 2, ID = 4**" as a string output.

I am using the following to get the corresponding ID in the City field:

```
df = df.withColumn("City", expr("case when City IS NULL then ID " + "else City end"))
```

The above returns the following:

| ID | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NY |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | LA |
| 4 | 4 |

I would just like to return the ID numbers. The output should not be in a dataframe.

Comment: `ids = df.filter("City is null").select("ID").collect()`

Comment: See solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262762/filter-pyspark-dataframe-column-with-none-value

Comment: @blackbishop thank you! This worked. I am unable to select this as an answer though - not seeing an answer option provided.